# как выровнять центры осей картинки и контейнера

Tags: css

как выровнять центры осей картинки и контейнера если у картинки задан фиксированный размер,  а размер контейнера плавающий?

нужно чтобы центр контейнера(пересечение осей х и у) совпадало с центром( пересечение х и у) картинки

Comment: Родителю, `position:relative;`  Дочернему элементу `position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Comment: @Air благодарю. с фоном так-же?

Comment: Для фона есть такое правило, как `background-position: X% Y% ; && background-size: X% || (px) Y% || (px)  ;`

Comment: @Air  благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отцентрируйте картинку, задав внутри контейнера выравнивание с помощью Flexbox

[Результат на CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/GVQRva)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
    background: #ccc;
    min-height: 100vh;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354">
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш способ тоже рабочий. спасибо большое

Comment: @андрейпупкин, да не за что.Вот только на данном сайте, если ответ является решением, его принято помечать решением. Это как альтернатива "спасибо"

Comment: спасибо. отметил